# Why aren't my values coming from webservice inserting into select tag via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

so I have am making a GET request to my webservice class to get the emails of all users to store inside of `<option>` tags within `<select>` tags. When I print to the console, everything looks correct, but my `<select>` tags aren't even showing up on the page when I run it in the browser. I have ensured that the id that I'm grabbing is correct, the values are being received from the webservice, information is being parsed correctly, etc... Also, this function is using "onload" from the body tag. Here is my code:

```
 function loader() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let val = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let len = val.length;
            document.getElementById("ulistval").innerHTML = "select name='emailname' id='emailget'>";
            for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
                document.getElementById("ulistval").innerHTML = `<option value="${val[i].email}">${val[i].email}</option>`;
                console.log(`<option value="${val[i].email}">${val[i].email}</option>`);
            }
            document.getElementById("ulistval").innerHTML = "</select>"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("ulistval").innerHTML = "</select>"; ` <-- you are not building a string! You are replacing all of the content of the element with `</select>`. Build a string, set the innerHTML, fix your opening select tag

Comment: Thank you so much. After concatenating them all in a string and then sending the value to the id, it worked! I appreciate it!